# Screen resolution parameter setup, session bean and JSF Phase Listener

Tags: jsf, session, servlets, javabeans, phase

I am currently facing the following issue and I would appreciate if someone could help me out here. I am pretty new to JSF...

I have a JSF application with the following architecture:
The main index.html site contains a Javascript that opens an XMLHttpRequest to a servlet with the user screen resolution parameters. The servlet receives the request, extracts the screen resoultuion parameters and sends it to a session bean object:

```
String wth = request.getParameter("width");
String hgt = request.getParameter("heigh");
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
Object o = session.getAttribute("mainSessionBean");
MainSessionBean mainSessionBean = (MainSessionBean) o;
mainSessionBean.setScreenWidth(wth);
mainSessionBean.setScreenHeight(hgt);
```

Now this works on its own way, the problem is that at the very first page (index.html) the session bean object does not have the parameter yet should we navigate to another site the session bean does have the parameter. I believe this means that the index.html gets rendered/created before the session bean object gets created. Should we navigate to another site the session bean object does have the necessary screen size values. So, where I am now is that I can set up the JSF elements dynamically according to the user's screen resolution but only from the second visited page onwards.

What I would like to achieve is that the Javascript initiates its XMLHttpRequest to the servlet, the servlet then calls the session bean, passes the necesary screen size resolution and when the first page gets created then the necessary parameters are already in place.

I am not entirely sure I am doing this on the right way, but any advice, link to the right sort of resource will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The process:

1. Your browser sends a HTTP request to your server
2. Your server initializes session and replies with the index.html page
3. Your javascript sends back screen dimensions

How do you want to have the screen dimensions available at point 2? The best you can do is, after point 3, automatically reload the index.html page (make a check, if it is the first request in the session just send the JS and the redirection, if it is not send the actual login html)

Comment: SJuan, Thanks for the reply, I was thinking about the reload option, which then ensures that the backing bean has the necessary parameters from the client side thus creating the JSF elements with the right dimensions, but I tried to avoid the unnecessary reload.

Comment: If I will implement this solution, how would I check that the session is new, is the isNew() method would be sufficient for this purpouse?

Comment: You could just check if the screen attributes are set. The problem with that approach is that, if someone's browser does not send the JS, it will break.

Comment: Thanks I will give it another try.